# Output variables by "expect"

Tags: shell, tcl, expect

I use `expect` and already established an `ssh connection`.

I want to see the result of `ls -1 /etc/folder/`.

I tried

```
send "files=$(ls -1 /etc/folder/)"
put $files
```

but failed.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The *big* problem you've got is that there are variables locally and variables on the remote system and they are not the same thing at all. While yes, it is possible to build systems which make variables (appear to be) shared automatically between systems, it most certainly does not happen by default. This is a conceptual thing that you *must get right* or you will not ever write correct code except by accident.

Apart from that, you have a lesser problem of that you're not sending the command correctly, and are not handling the result coming back. Assuming you know that the prompt on the remote system is just a `$` and that the files don't ever start with that, you need to do this.

```
# Note the \r; it is like pressing <Return> and is important!
send "ls -1 /etc/folder \r"
# Now we collect the output:
set files {}
expect {
    "$ " {
        puts $files
    }
    -re {^[^$].*$} {
        # This grabs a line that doesn't start with $ and adds it to the list
        lappend files $expect_out(0,string)
        # Now we go back to waiting for another line or the prompt
        exp_continue
    }
}
```

And that's *exactly* how you do it. Yes, it does take quite a bit of code…

Comment: You may find you have carriage returns at the end of each element of the files list. You may want `-re {^([^$].*)\r?$} {lappend files $expect_out(1,string); exp_continue}`